# What does the "Your PC does not meet the minimum requirements to play Pro Evolution Soccer" error mean?

Tags: pro-evolution-soccer-2013

My computer Has the following specification:

```
Operating System:     Windows 8 Pro 64-bit (6.2, Build 9200) (9200.win8_gdr.130531-1504
Processor:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2330M CPU @ 2.20GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.2GHz
Memory:               8192MB RAM
Available OS Memory:  8126MB RAM
Page File:            1035MB used, 8306MB available
Display Memory:       1850 MB
Card name:            Intel(R) HD Graphics Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.2)
Current Mode:         1366 x 768 (32 bit) (60Hz)
```

Comment: Sorry, to help you we're gonna need more information. What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: My bet goes to the onboard graphics chip causing the issue.

Comment: My guess would be that the integrated graphics card does not meet the system requirements.

Answer (score 6):

The "Settings" option in the Pro Evolution Soccer launcher will show you more information on how you're failing the minimum system requirements check;

[image]

Click on the "Specifications" tab and you will see a colour coded screen highlighting where the problem is;

[image]

You will need to fix these problems before you can play. Since you've mentioned you're using an integrated Intel graphics chipset in your question, this is most likely where the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Either your laptop only has an Intel Graphics card and you can't play this game.

Or it uses Optimus technology, in which case you should read this article:
http://ucdavistechtalk.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/how-to-switch-between-intel-graphics-and-nvidia-with-optimus/

Comment: Hey Refalm, welcome to Arqade and thanks for the contribution. If you have time, could you summarize the content of the video inside the link in case the blog gets removed or goes down?

Comment: Sure :>

Open the "NVIDIA Control Panel" from the Control Panel, or by the notification area. Click on "Manage 3D settings". Open the tab "Program settings". From there, find the game in the list, or add it yourself. Then select "High-performance NVIDIA processor". Don't forget to click on "Apply".

Answer (score 1):

It definitely seems to be the graphics, I would at least try changing the `VRAM` size in the `BIOS` if possible to 256 or what ever is greatest and try again.